# Cannot Connect To Remote Sql Server With ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string

I'm developing a Winform project that needs to connect to a remote Sql server.
I'm using Entity Framework as ORM. Here is my connectionstring

```
<add name="RemoteConnection" connectionString="Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=****;User Id=****;Password=*****;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get the following error when i want to connect remote sql server

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Everything works fine with SQL server management studio, i'm able to see databases and have access to them, but when in comes to code i get error

Comment: You have chose Windows authentication while adding entity model, instead select SQL Server Authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> User Id=****;Password=*****;Integrated Security=True

is wrong. If you want to use Integrated security, you should not pass any credential (leave only `Integrated security= True`).

If instead you want to use SQL Server login (+ password), pass only them and exclude `Integrated security= True`